# AS3 Memory management when instantiating extended classes

Tags: actionscript-3, inheritance, memory-management, class

I'm developing an AS3 application which has some memory leaks I can't find, so I'd like to ask some newbie questions about memory management.

Imagine I have a class named BaseClass, and some classes that extend this one, such as ClassA, ClassB, etc.

I declare a variable:

```
myBaseClass:BaseClass = new ClassA();
```

After a while, I use it to instantiate a new object:

```
myBaseClass = new ClassB();
```

some time after

```
myBaseClass = new ClassC();
```

and the same thing keeps happening every x millis, triggered by a timer.

Is there any memory problem here? Are the unused instances correctly deleted by the garbage collector?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have *no* other references to the instance (or, possibly, its contents), the garbage collector will clean them up. However, the time before cleanup is, as far as I know, indeterminate (there might be some hard timeline in use, but I've never seen it documented). If you're creating a huge number of instances, you might use up a lot of memory before the first ever gets cleaned up.

There is an AS call (the name of which escapes me at the moment) to force a GC run, but it shouldn't normally be necessary. If you find it necessary, you almost certainly need to rethink how your application works.

Comment: Is there any debugging way to check how many references are pointing an instance?

Comment: this is the way to force GC but please do not use it. 
http://www.gskinner.com/blog/archives/2006/08/as3_resource_ma_2.html
try {
   new LocalConnection().connect('foo');
   new LocalConnection().connect('foo');
} catch (e:*) {}

Comment: @araid try this memory monitor. It is handy so that you can try add/removing lines of code and then watch in realtime the memory usuage http://github.com/mrdoob/stats.as

Comment: That is the old way to force the GC, now you should (but your really should not) use System.gc();

Comment: I think flashbuilder has a profiler as does flashdevelop, which both allow you to see how many instantiations there are of a class and what the maximum instantiation count was.

Answer (score 0):

If myBaseClass is the only stored reference to

> new ClassA()

and you assign something else to myBaseClass

> new ClassB()

then there will be no reference pointing to ClassA and the garbage collector should find it when it runs.

However, if you give myBaseClass to a library or class that stores its own reference to that object, when you reassign myBaseClass there will still be a reference pointing to the ClassA and the garbage collector will not clean it up, creating a memory leak. Normally a well written library will provide you with a way to remove the reference. e.g.

```
var child:Sprite = new Sprite()
// one reference to the new Sprite

stage.addChild(child); // assume stage stores reference
// two references to the new Sprite

/**
 * assume the following:
 *
 * child = null; 
 *
 * one reference would still remain in stage
 * garbage collector will not clean up the sprite
 */

stage.removeChild(child); // assume stage clears reference
// one reference left
child = null;
// no reference to the sprite, garbage collector will clean it up
```

Hope this clears things up a bit. Essentially you want to keep track of how many references there are to an object, if you suspect it to be leaking memory.

I know that FlashDevelop has a profiler that is quite useful for finding these bugs. Also, you need to know that when the garbage collector runs... it will free up memory and give a saw tooth pattern to your memory profiler.

- [Good example code for demonstrating profiling in Actionscript 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2613753/831203)
- [AS3 Memory Leak Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7256317/831203)